# MySQL space comparsion hell

Tags: mysql

Why this query:

```
SELECT 
    "hello" = " hello",
    "hello" = "hello ",
    "hello" <> "hello ",
    "hello" LIKE "hello ",
    "hello" LIKE "hello%"
```

returns me these results:

```
"hello" = " hello"         -> 0
"hello" = "hello "         -> 1
"hello" <> "hello "        -> 0
"hello" LIKE "hello "      -> 0
"hello" LIKE "hello%"      -> 1
```

In particular, I was expecting `"hello" = "hello "` to be `false` and `"hello" <> "hello "` to be `true` (the `LIKE` in this case, behaves exactly as I wanted).

Why MySQL compares spaces in such an arbitrary and inconsistent way ? (such as returning 0 on `"hello" = " hello"` AND 1 on `"hello" = "hello "`).

Is there any way to configure MySQL to work ALWAYS in "strict mode" (in other words, to make it always behave like `LIKE` for the varchar/text comparsion) ?

Sadly i'm using a proprietary framework and I cannot force it to always use the `LIKE` in queries for text comparsions or trimming all the inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `"hello" = " hello"    -- 0`,
     Because it is not an exact match
- `"hello" = "hello "    -- 1`,
     Because trailing spaces are ignored for varchar types
- `"hello" <> "hello "   -- 0`,
     Because trailing spaces are ignored for varchar types
- `"hello" LIKE "hello " -- 0`,
     Because trailing spaces are ignored for varchar types and `LIKE` performs matching on a per-char basis
- `"hello" LIKE "hello%" -- 1`,
     Because it is a partial pattern matching

If you want strict checking, you can use `binary` on values to be compared.

```
mysql> select binary('hello')=binary('hello ') bin_eq, 'hello'='hello ' eq;
+--------+----+
| bin_eq | eq |
+--------+----+
|      0 |  1 |
+--------+----+
```

***Refer to***:

- [MySQL: Comparison Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html)

Answer (score 0):

The trailing spaces are omitted if the column is of type char or varchar. See the discussion in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html).

Comment: @Downvoter : this answer is the best point for the OP's problem

Answer (score 0):

All MySQL collations are of type PADSPACE. This means that all CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT values in MySQL are compared without regard to any trailing spaces. “Comparison” in this context does not include the LIKE pattern-matching operator, for which trailing spaces are significant.

Comment: Thanks to @TechGuy for sharing such a useful link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html